# How to programmatically make an NSWindow fullscreen using Lion?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

For Lion development, I want to programmatically make an `NSWindow` fullscreen, and back to normal, exactly as if the user clicked on the fullscreen button.

I tried `setStyleMask:` (which I saw can be used for checking), but it only resulted in the title bar disappearing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `-toggleFullScreen:` on the window you want to change after you've configured everything for full screen.

Comment: Could you specify an example?